# How to delete the space before and after the 'itemize' or 'enumerate'?

Tags: itemize

My code is shown below.

```
\textbf{I. Introduction}\\
\hspace*{1em} \textbf {A. Background:}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\item[1.] The differences between clear vowels and conversational vowels are widely studies.
\begin{itemize}
\item[a.]Vowel Duration: Clear vowels are generally longer than conversational vowels
\item[b.] Dynamic Formant Movement: Clear vowels exhibit greater movement than naturally produced vowels.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
abcccccccccccccdfdfadsdfasdfsfssfdsdfsfa
```

And the result is shown below. I just want to delete the space before and after the item. I have already set the length as 0pt, but it is not working. Is there something wrong with my code? Thank you very much!!
[image]

Comment: Load ` enumitem` and use `begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*., nosep] \item ...\end{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bernard has already suggested in a comment, you may want to load the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) package, switch from `itemize` to `enumerate` environments, and start up both `enumerate` environments with the option `nosep`.

The following screenshot shows the outputs of both your original code and of the code that implements the preceding suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
% Before:
\hrule
\textbf{I. Introduction}

\hspace*{1em}\textbf {A. Background:}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\item[1.] The differences between clear vowels and conversational 
          vowels are widely studies.
\begin{itemize}
\item[a.]Vowel Duration: Clear vowels are generally longer than 
         conversational vowels
\item[b.] Dynamic Formant Movement: Clear vowels exhibit greater 
         movement than naturally produced vowels.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
% After:
\textbf{I. Introduction}

\hspace*{1em}\textbf{A. Background:}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=\arabic*.]
\item The differences between clear vowels and conversational 
      vowels are widely studies.
   \begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=\alph*.]
   \item Vowel Duration: Clear vowels are generally longer than 
         conversational vowels
   \item Dynamic Formant Movement: Clear vowels exhibit greater 
         movement than naturally produced vowels.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\end{document}
```